# MongoDB: storing data in decimal format

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following document that I would like to store on MongoDB.

```
{
  "date": "2019-02-19 17:10:60.000Z",
  "thickness": 7.85458285
}
```

I would like the `thickness` value to be stored with the given precision and I've read that there's the [Decimal datatype](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) in MongoDB.

At the moment I have the following piece of code that inserts the given value, but when I check the stored value it's a double.

```
$col = $mongoConnection->selectDatabase($db)->selectCollection($collectionName);
$col->insertOne(array("date" => $date, "thickness" => $tck));
```

How can I force to store that field as a decimal in my PHP application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can use BSON type classes in php, you can use this documentation
http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-decimal128.php

```
$tck = new MongoDB\BSON\Decimal128('7.85458285')
$col = $mongoConnection->selectDatabase($db)->selectCollection($collectionName);
$col->insertOne(array("date" => $date, "thickness" => $tck));
```